# Value converter fails on 2nd run but succeeds with try catch C#

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a combo-box im populating with a collection of objects in my ViewModel.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ChangelistComboBox"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding MyObjectSelectionIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList, Mode=OneWay}"
          Margin="5"
          Grid.Column="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyObjectToComboBoxConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Im using a Converter to convert parameters from the object to a displaystring that shows up in the ComboBox

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(MyObject), typeof(string))]
class MyObjectToComboBoxConverter : ValueConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        try {
            MyObject theObject = (MyObject)value;
            int id = theObject.Id;
            return (((id != -1) ? id.ToString() : "default") + " : " + theObject.Description);
        } catch(InvalidCastException e) {
            return (String)value;
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return new MyObject(); //Not used
    }
}
    abstract class ValueConverterBase : IValueConverter
{
    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

In the Model the list is defined as:

```
        private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _MyObjectList;
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectList {
        get
        {
            if (_MyObjectList != null) { return _MyObjectList; } else { return new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(); }
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MyObjectList != value) {
                _MyObjectList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyObjectList");
            }
        }
    }
```

In the ViewModel the MyObjectList is simply referenced from the model through the interface:

```
        public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectList {
        get
        {
            if (Model != null) {
                return Model.MyObjectList;
            } else {
                return new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Without the TryCatch, this converter crashes when my MyObjectList is updated. It gives an error like Cannot cast type string to object on the   `MyObject theObject = (MyObject)value;` line

With the TryCatch the converter works as intended. It even returns a correctly assembled string. The problem is I get InvalidCastExceptions in the error log, which isnt good. Also I have no idea why it works despite the exception.

The only hunch I have is that for some reason the object is being converted twice, once from object to string and then it tries to convert the string to string and fails there. I cant figure out why it would be doing that though.

Comment: Through debugging i can see that the InvalidCastExceptions happen when the ObservableCollection<Object> ObjectList is added to in the Model. Once the Command is finished, it runs the converter again for some reason at which point it goes through successfully

Comment: Since you are already using the debugger, i wonder why you don't seem to attempt debugging your actual ObjectToComboBoxConverter...

Comment: Im not sure how to do that.. The Converter receives an empty string as a value, which causes it to fail on the cast to the Object. I dont know why its getting an empty string instead of an Object like it should.

Comment: Also, what is this silly line `Object theObject = (Object)value;`? The C# keyword `object` (lowercase) is just a synonym for `System.Object`. So, unless you made a custom class named Object, that code line is not making any sense. And if you have a custom class named Object, then this class name is a very bad idea as it is easily confused with System.Object...

Comment: You don't know how to debug? You just said in your previous comment that you were debugging (something). I am utterly confused...

Comment: I just changed my object name to Object to make it a bit more conscise but i guess it created extra confusion. Also im debugging but im not very good at it

Comment: If you are still feeling your way around in the debugger, maybe this can help you a bit: [Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger). (The error message "_Cannot cast type string to object_" should be quite telling about why the converter fails -- why not start inspecting what the content of that string actually is. It could perhaps give you a clue about where this string is coming from...)

Comment: I think it will helps to have a look on your ViewModel and to see how you will add the items in your ObservableCollection.

Comment: What is __ValueConverterBase__??

Comment: I added some more info to the main post

Comment: As a hint: replace `NotifyPropertyChanged("MyObjectList");` to `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyObjectList));` the `nameof` will avoid typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MVVM IValueConverter Convert method getting empty string argument when expecting a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946104/mvvm-ivalueconverter-convert-method-getting-empty-string-argument-when-expecting)

Just found this which seems to be the same issue that I'm experiencing. I dont fully understand the explanation for it given there, but if modifying the Convert to accept an empty string is a viable solution i can live with that

Still feels like a hack but beggars cant be choosers i guess

Answer (score 0):

You bind the ComboBox source to a list of `MyObject`, so the value should never be of type string. I guess there is a problem in your model state.

The way you are binding your view is correct, also the first version of the converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(MyObject), typeof(string))]
class MyObjectToComboBoxConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        try {
            var theObject = (MyObject)value;
            var id = theObject.Id;
            return (((id != -1) ? id.ToString() : "default") + " : " + theObject.Description);
        } catch(InvalidCastException e) {
            return (string)value;
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please start to change your ViewModel to:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
```

You need to implement the `OnPropertyChangeEvent` on the properties of the `MyObject` model (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection)
so you only need to set the `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel to an empty instance by default.

Then adding items:

```
MyObjectList.Add(new MyObject{ id=1, Description="First"});
```